# Massless limit of the Klein-Gordon propagator

Tags: quantum-field-theory, field-theory, klein-gordon-equation

I am working with the propagator associated to the Klein-Gordon equation, as derived in "Quantum Physics a functional integral point of view", James Glimm, Arthur Jaffe or as derived here: http://www.wiese.itp.unibe.ch/lectures/fieldtheory.pdf § 5.4

It turns out that the propagator can be evaluated, and a close-form expression for it can be given, namely:

$$ C \left( m; \mathbf{x} - \mathbf{y} \right) = \left(\frac{1}{2 \pi}\right)^{-\frac{d}{2}} \left(\frac{m}{\left| \mathbf{x} - \mathbf{y} \right|}\right)^{\frac{d-2}{2}} K_{\frac{d-2}{2}} \left( m \left| \mathbf{x} - \mathbf{y} \right| \right) $$

where $K$ is the modified Bessel function of the second kind. I'd want to take the massless limit in two dimensions; when setting $d=2$ and $m=0$ one of the terms in the r.h.s. of the equation evaluates to $0^0$ while the modified Bessel function goes to infinity. How do I calculate the massless limit for the Klein-Gordon propagator in 2D?

Thank you!

Comment: Related: http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/13164/2451

Answer (score 3):

A nice way to see how the correlation function behaves is described [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mermin%E2%80%93Wagner_theorem) where it is shown that the propagator goes as 
$$C(r)=\frac{1}{2\pi}\log(r)$$
which can also be seen as given by *Qmechanics* hint. Now the interesting thing is not that it diverges at $r=0$ (this happens even in 4D where $C(r)=1/4 \pi^2 r^2$) but that it also diverges as $r\to \infty$. This is an infrared divergence I had not come across before. The Wikipedia article linked above states that this makes a two dimensional massless scalar field slightly tricky to define mathematically and also that you cannot have spontaneous breaking of a continuous symmetry in two dimensions. Very interesting!

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest you first set $d=2$ giving
$$C \left( m; \mathbf{x} - \mathbf{y} \right) = \frac{1}{2 \pi}  K_0 \left( m \left| \mathbf{x} - \mathbf{y} \right| \right)$$
and then take the massless limit.

Comment: Maybe I should've mentioned that, I've tried this approach... When taking the $m \longrightarrow 0$ limit the Bessel function goes to $\infty$ so that the propagator is infinite everywhere...

Answer (score 2):

Hint: Use e.g. that the modified Bessel function $K_0$ behaves as minus the logarithm for small arguments near zero.

Reference:

1. Abramowitz & Stegun, *Handbook of Mathematical Functions,* p. 375, eq. (9.6.8). For an online version see e.g. [here](http://mintaka.sdsu.edu/faculty/wfw/ABRAMOWITZ-STEGUN/page_375.htm).

Comment: Link now dead. Try [google search](https://www.google.com/search?as_q=abramowitz+stegun+handbook+mathematical+functions) instead.