# Use and understanding of higher-order correlation functions

Tags: double-slit-experiment, quantum-optics, correlation-functions

The correlation function g1 is pretty easy to understand and the relation to young's double slit experiment is also clear to me.

In every quantum optics book I read so far correlation functions $g^n(x_1, ... , x_{2n})$ of an order greater than 1 are defined, but not related to an experiment or explained any further.

What is an example for an experiment that requires a correlation function of a higher order?

In my understanding $g^1(x_1,x_2)$ gives the similarities between two functions for different $\tau$. How is this possible for more than one function, if $g^n(x_1,...,x_{2n})$ is still scalar?

The definitions I used can be found in any book an quantum optics or here http://www.matthiaspospiech.de/files/studium/skripte/QOscript.pdf (p 64)

Comment: could you maybe add a link explaining what g1 means, in the context of the double slit experiment? or define what it means.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Okay, so I gather from the link that $G^{(k)}$ in your notation refers to the correlation between field values at $2k$ points, with $\varepsilon^+$ inserted at half of them and $\varepsilon^-$ inserted at the other half.

This concept of an $n$-point correlation function is very similar to the $n$th [moment](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Moment_%28mathematics%29) of a random variable or statistical distribution. For simplicity, consider an example with 1 dimension: A field over 1 time dimension (at a single point in space), described by a random variable. Now, we can consider the probability distribution of this random variable and talk of it's moments. The *mean* value would be called the 1st moment and the *variance* would be related to the second moment (it is in fact called the second *central* moment). Similarly, you can generalize to higher order moments which help *characerize the distribution*. The moments help you [characterize the distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Moment_%28mathematics%29#Significance_of_the_moments) and also give an intuitive feel for the function.

Generalize this concept to random variables which are fields over many-dimensional spacetime. That is what your correlation functions are.

Btw, for a gaussian distribution (non-interacting fields i.e. quadratic action), all odd moments vanish. (That might be the motivation for $G^{(k)}$ to be defined as the correlation between field values at $2k$ points... even though the actual physical theory you're considering will probably be interacting, else all correlation functions are fairly trivial).
Also, all even moments beyond the 2nd-moment are completely specified by the 1st and the 2nd moment. [Ref1](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Normal_distribution#Moments) and [Ref2](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/NormalDistribution.html)

If you had an interaction term in the hamiltonian/lagrangian involving 4 fields, then the 4-point correlation function would have 2 kinds of contributions:

1. 2 sets of 2-point correlation functions between pairs of points among those 4 points
2. A nontrivial contribution from the interaction term with one of it's field insertions at each of the 4 points.

So you can see that higher order correlations functions give you very important (an unique) information in an interacting physical theory.

Update: The (many) answers to [this SE question](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/3168/3998) might also shed some light on the discussion.